# IIS hangs when debugging with Visual Studio

Tags: iis, debugging, visual-studio-2013, time-out

I keep having this ridiculous issue that's driving me mad. I happen to debug some code with Visual Studio (attached to all w3wp) and let's say I get an exception and VS is set to catch all exceptions. I go check the exception and the item in cause, then I switch to browser to check something else and I go again in Visual Studio to check the item again and when I mouse over it, visual studio hangs like mad and takes around 10-15 seconds to come back. After that whatever I do I get the "previous operation has timed out" and iis is completely unresponsive, I cannot detach and it takes a ridiculous amount of time, somewhere around 5 minutes to come back. It's completely dead. I kill all w3wp, vssphost, recycle, iisreset and it still doesn't come back.

My colleagues don't have this issue, if it hangs they just reattach and bam, it works. For me, never. I have no idea what's different on my machine. Even on previous virtual machines, os installs same thing happened.

Settings of application pool:
[image]

I appreciate any sort of help. Also feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are jumping back and forth between IIS and VS, and in your description it sounds like a normal request timeout because you hit a breakpoint and did not continue from it? Is this what you are doing? 
IIS will timeout and kill the process you are debugging, as the server is no longer responding as you have a breakpoint stopping it or you take too long stepping through code. If you are running default settings it think it is after about 2 minutes. After this you will have to restart the IIS process and attach in VS again. You can always try to increase your request timeout on the site you are debugging.

Which version of VS are you running?